# automatic line feed with text on react native

Tags: ios, text, react-native

I'm actually trying to put a long text with react-native.
I've tried with property numberOfLines and lineBreakMode but nothing work, line is never break and text continues to be on one line until offscreen.

this is my code :

class PostList

```
class PostList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 6, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <Post content={'Populo invidunt maluisset sea cu, volumus fierent id sea. Est et clita lucilius tacimates. Sed brute definitionem an. Sed tollit vocibus maiestatis ne, hinc iisque feugiat an vis. Cibo recteque duo an. Ei ludus nusquam vel.'} />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

class Post

```
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window')

class Post extends Component {

    render(){
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <Text width={(width * 0.85) - 20} textAlign={'left'} style={styles.contentText}>
                    {this.props.content}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        )
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        margin: 15,
        width: width * 0.85,
        height: 300, 
        backgroundColor: 'white', 
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 139, 23, 0.7)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    textContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 10
    },
    nameText: {
        fontFamily: 'Aller-bold',
        fontSize: width / 26
    },
    contentText: {
        fontFamily: 'Aller',
        fontSize: width / 26
    }
})
```

result :

http://www.yagoshack.fr/?v=capturmum.png

So how can i do to for a line break is done every time a word reaches the end of view ?

Thank's

Comment: i've found solution : don't add flexDirection: 'row' in a container with text if you want only that :)